# Replacement for pageOverlayFields-Feature in TYPO3 8 and above

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In former TYPO3-Versions for localizing pages there was a fallback to fields of the default langauage by adding the field name to `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageOverlayFields']`

Since TYPO3 8.7 pageOverlayFields is removed.

How can I achieve the former behaviour in TYPO3 8 and above: Translating a page and get for instance images from the media field of the default language if media is not set in current language?

I have found a workaround here:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80149
an here:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83863

for the image thing. But with this the sliding feature is lost unfortunately.

Is there any other possibility to avoid, that the editor has to link the images again and again in every language?